# JQuery - Maintain div visible on hover with outside trigger

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using JQuery to show a hidden Div using the `slideToggle` function. This works fine but i want to keep the Div visible whilst the mouse is hovering over it.

I have searched a lot and I think that I need to do something with adding classes but I only just started with JQuery today and I'm having trouble understanding it. Any help greatly appreciated, I'm sure what I have written isn't the most efficient way to do it.

Thanks

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="navHeader"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="navContent" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="totalContent"></div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#navHeader").mouseover(function () {
        $("#navContent").slideToggle(1000);
    });
    $("#navHeader").mouseout(function () {
        $("#navContent").slideToggle(1000);
    });
});    
</script>
```

I tried adding this and playing about with it to maintain the div visible but it doesn't work.

```
$("#navContent").hover(function(){
    $("#navContent").show();
});
```

Comment: Is the HTML structure fixed or can that be changed?

Comment: Fixed if possible, its to replace the Nav of an already made site.

Comment: So moving `<div id="navContent" style="display:none;"></div>` to be the child of `<div id="navHeader"></div>` isn't an option?

Comment: Just an suggestion. Instead of `$("#navHeader").mouseover(function () {
        $("#navContent").slideToggle(1000);
    });
    $("#navHeader").mouseout(function () {
        $("#navContent").slideToggle(1000);
    });` you can do the same with `$("#navHeader").hover(function () {
        $("#navContent").slideToggle(1000);
    });`.

Comment: You can achieve this without JavaScript using the `:hover` psuedo-selector and transitions: http://jsfiddle.net/7DwLr/. In browsers that do not support transitions, it will just hide/show, but it is still functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with, but you need to rearrange your elements.
The navContent needs to be child of navHeader
So this  may or may not work for you, as you might be restricted in that sense...

But here it is....

```
       $('#navHeader').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('#navContent').slideToggle(); });
```

Notice the CSS though as well, you need to compensate for the height of the header element, however high it is.....so that the menu is below.

http://jsfiddle.net/8xdV3/1/

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to move the content to a child position you can do the following:

1. Create a timeout when leaving the nav header or content.
2. In return you have to clear the timeout if you hover over the content so it doesn't hide.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hoverTimeout;

    $("#navHeader").mouseover(function () {
        if (hoverTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
        }
        $("#navContent").slideToggle(1000);
    });

    $("#navContent").mouseover(function () {
        if (hoverTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
        }
    });

    $("#navHeader, #navContent").mouseout(function () {
        hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#navContent").slideToggle(1000);
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/joshthecoder/crPcZ/)